# Keystone connection fail

Tags: openstack, keystone

I have install Keystone following [the guide for Ubuntu14.04](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/keystone-concepts.html)

When i try to create a service entity:

```
openstack service create --type identity \
  --description "Openstack Identity" keystone
```

I obtain:

```
INFO: urllib3.connectionpool Starting new HTTP connection (1): controller
ERROR: cliff.app Internal Server Error (HTTP 500)
```

I am sure that i have connection to "controller",and mysql is configured to accept connections from any host.

My configuration file of keystone is:

```
[DEFAULT] admin_token =ADMIN 
admin_port=35357 
public_port=5000

[database] 
connection = mysql://keystone:keystone@controller/keystone

[memcache] 
servers = localhost:11211

[token] 
provider = keystone.token.providers.uuid.Provider 
driver =keystone.token.persistence.backends.memcache.Token

[revoke] 
driver = keystone.contrib.revoke.backends.sql.Revoke

[DEFAULT] 
verbose = True
```

And Apache is configured as shown in [the guide](http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/install-guide/install/apt/content/keystone-concepts.html).

Where am i failing?

Comment: You're getting a 500 error from the server.  What errors is the keystone server logging (possibly in `/var/log/keystone/keystone.log`, depending on your configuration)?

Answer (score 2):

I dont' know if you found and answer already but I also had this problem. 
The reason was quite simple really, one of the instructions on the guide didn't work for me. This is the one:

```
# apt-get install ubuntu-cloud-keyring
# echo "deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu" \
"trusty-updates/kilo main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-kilo.list
```

So I was not using the kilo packages but older ones (urllib3 being one of them). How to fix this? Just create this file manually:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/cloudarchive-kilo.list
```

And just write this inside:

> deb http://ubuntu-cloud.archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty-updates/kilo main

Finish it with this command, to make the update:

```
# apt-get update && apt-get dist-upgrade
```

You should have a lot of new updates now. 
There you go, hope it helps, it fixed the problem for me at least.

Bruno